# Why closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I had asked [Would a lightsaber melt or vaporize a bullet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30497/would-a-lightsaber-melt-or-vaporize-a-bullet), which is currently closed as a duplicate of [Why would a slug thrower be more effective against a lightsaber/Jedi than a blaster?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13695/why-would-a-slug-thrower-be-more-effective-against-a-lightsaber-jedi-than-a-blas) I do not see how these two questions are duplicates as the former merely asks for the effects of lightsabers on an object as opposed to the latter asking for pro and cons of two weapons (slugthrowers and blasters).

Yes, my question can be related to [Why would a slug thrower be more effective against a lightsaber/Jedi than a blaster?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13695/why-would-a-slug-thrower-be-more-effective-against-a-lightsaber-jedi-than-a-blas) because whether a bullet melts or vaporizes is probably a factor in the effectiveness of a slugthrower against a lightsaber, but they are hardly the same question.

Answer (score 1):

What determines if questions are duplicates is usually "will the answer to one answer the other?"

In this case, the accepted answer includes this:

> Blaster bolts can be reflected, slugs will be burned up by the blade. This removes a significant counterattack from the Jedi.

While not the most detailed answer to your question, it shows there's some potential overlap.  That's probably what prompted the closure.

However, as the question has since been re-opened, it seems clear the community agrees there was not enough overlap to justify a closure.

Comment: But it's not cited, it could easily be just a (potentially subconscious) assumption.

Comment: +1 I do not understand why this answer would be downvoted. Anyone who actually knows this to be false (not to be the reason for closure) would have to know the *real* reason; and refuse to share it.

Comment: @luserdroog In fairness, most of my downvotes were from before I edited it.  Since my original answer implied the closure was justified, the downvotes were justified.

Comment: Ah, I see. Still, there's nothing wrong with it *now*.

Comment: Downvotes on meta don't mean anything other than "I disagree". They have no bearing on rep. If one is going to change the thrust of a meta answer (or any answer, really) it's worth considering simple writing an additional answer.

Comment: @Beofett - I was mostly talking to luserdroog, actually.